# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' - Homestead

Tags: php, homestead

I have been working on somebody's web app which he uses Cakephp and laravel. The site was working very fine until I decided to re-establish homestead (I just re-extracted the zip file which includes the same homestead version and configurations). I am now encountering this issue  **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'"** showing in the console when loading it to my browser. I believe that the problem is somewhere in my php.ini or some configuration regarding vagrant or my virtual machine since the site was working fine before and I didn't mess with the site files itself.

[image]

[image]

I am still new to these things, So can someone help me with that?

Comment: Is the second image code in a `.php` file?

Comment: in a .ctp file inside views folder of cakephp framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was in php.ini in my vagrant machine. I have to set `short_open_tag = On`

I use php7 --> the path to php.ini exists in **/etc/php/7.2/fpm** and **/etc/php/7.2/cli**

I just added this `short_open_tag = On` at the bottom of each php.ini file and reloaded the vagrant machine with `--provision` tag and the problem gone.